# boolean string parsing behaviour in scala-native

Tags: scala-native

what could be the reason for a normal parsing code to give on the scale-native side(after compiling) the below exception:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: For input string: "false"
at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class$.parseBoolean(Unknown Source)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Unknown Source)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Unknown Source)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class$.map(Unknown Source)
at example.Main$.main(Unknown Source)
at <none>.main(Unknown Source)
at <none>.__libc_start_main(Unknown Source)
at <none>._start(Unknown Source)
at <none>.(Unknown Source)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit code: 1
```

data: parsing the below line

203358,99103,false,3.6,1.0,,0,0.0,0.0,0.0,None,None,None,-1,0

code in scala:

```
val objArr=line.split(",")

 objArr(2).toBoolean
```

Answer (score 0):

this was because of the use of an old version. check below for details.

https://github.com/issues?q=is%3Aissue+author%3Afsaab+archived%3Afalse+is%3Aclosed